# how to set round corners in images in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimageview, calayer

I need to set image to button image should be in rounded corner

```
[camBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

cambtn should be button i need **@"camera.png"** should be rounded corners plz help i how to write